# setRotation change the ImageView position

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, image-rotation

In the code below, I'm trying to replace a sticker with an `imageView` keeping the same **[Width, Height, TranslateX, TranslateY, and Rotation]** of the sticker to give it to the `imageView` :

```
            transX = selectedSticker.getTransX();
            transY = selectedSticker.getTransY();
            rotation = selectedSticker.getCurrentAngle();
            
            ImageView mHoverView = findViewById(R.id.drawingView);
            mHoverView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) stickerWidth, (int) stickerHeight));
            
            mHoverView.setTranslationX(transX);
            mHoverView.setTranslationY(transY);
            mHoverView.setRotation(rotation);
            mHoverView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog);
            mHoverView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

When I click on **REPLACE** button to replace the sticker with `imageView`, everything works just fine, the problem starts ***when I rotate*** the sticker and clicks on the **REPLACE** button, the `imageView` takes the same rotation as the sticker, but it set in the wrong position (**the imageView is not rotated around it center**) :

e.g.

**NO ROTATION :**

[image]

**WITH ROTATION :**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I didn't set the `PivotX` and `PivotY` so the view is not rotated around the center, here's the full code :

```
float[] values = new float[9];
selectedSticker.getMatrix().getValues(values);
float dx = values[2];
float dy = values[5];
mHoverView.setPivotX(0.0f);
mHoverView.setPivotY(0.0f);
mHoverView.setTranslationX(dx);
mHoverView.setTranslationY(dy);
mHoverView.setRotation(rotation);
mHoverView.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you have to obtain correct translation values by re-calculating the transform matrix that is compatible to the View's transform.

```
//mHoverView.setTranslationX(transX);
//mHoverView.setTranslationY(transY);

Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setTranslate(transX, transY);
m.postRotate(rotation);
float[] offset = { 0.0F, 0.0F };
m.mapPoints(offset);

mHoverView.setTranslationX(offset[0]);
mHoverView.setTranslationY(offset[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, unfortunately, it does not work, now the `mHoverView` lose the rotation angle and positioned in the wrong place

Comment: Oh so. Then I have no idea. The cause of problem must exist in another part of your code that is not shown in your post.